# Access the DOM of the connected project from the Electron application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, electron

I have a web application on AngularJS running on localhost. I want to open it on the Electron and add a pop-up window that should only be in the desktop version. How do I add a new functionality without touching the original project using only the Electron application?

Actually I want to expand the guest page by adding a block with inspect mode of the DOM.

The page is connected as follows:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false
        }
    })

mainWindow.loadURL('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
```

Comment: you can run any code in loaded page with [`mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback)

Comment: @pergy ok, it works, but the script is passed by a string, can I pass the .js file to webContents.executeJavaScript?

Comment: > can I pass the .js file to webContents.executeJavaScript? : 
no, you can't.